# Button changes text to "[object promise]" on click. How do I stop that?

Tags: javascript, html, function, asynchronous

I am trying to call a table from a json file when clicking a button, and that is working fine. But when I click the button, it changes the text inside the button to "[object Promise]". I do not want the text or anything else on the button design to change. How do I stop it from doing that?

Code in html:

```
<button class="tableButton" id="drikker-btn" onclick="drikkeClick()">
    <p>Drikke</p>
</button>


    <div id="table">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Bilde</th>
                    <th>Produktnavn</th>
                    <th>Pris</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="data-output">
                <!-- Se script.js -->
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Code in JS:

```
function drikkeClick() {
    varbtnX = document.getElementById("drikker-btn").innerHTML = 
        fetch("drikker.json")
        .then(function(response){
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(drikker){
            let placeholder = document.querySelector("#data-output");
            let out = "";
            for(let product of drikker){
                out += `
                    <tr>
                        <td> <img src='${product.image}'> </td>
                        <td>${product.name}</td>
                        <td>${product.price}</td>
                    </tr>
                `;
            }
        
            placeholder.innerHTML = out;
        });
}
```

I have tried making the function async, by writing "async" in front off "function", but that did nothing.
I also tried manually writing a code-snippet that changes the text in the button back to what it originally said, but that did nothing as well.

Comment: "varbtnX = document.getElementById("drikker-btn").innerHTML = " is likely something that you don't want to include. this is what is changing your button

Answer (score 1):

```js
(async function loadData() {
    const response = await fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products");
    // parse JSON (error handling omitted here)
    const parsed = await response.json();
    const placeholder = document.querySelector("#data-output");
    
    const productRows = parsed.map(product => {
      const row = document.createElement("tr");
      row.replaceChildren(
        createCell(product.id), 
        createCell(product.title));
      return row;
    });
    placeholder.replaceChildren(...productRows);
})();

function createCell(content){
  const cell = document.createElement("td");
  cell.innerText = content;
  return cell;
}
```

```html
    <div id="table">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="data-output">
                <!-- Se script.js -->
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Just making a function `async` does not really make sense when you do not `await` it somewhere. If a you don't await the [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) never resolves and you get the output you're seeing `[object promise]`. So you need to `await` the `Promise` before using it to set some UI texts. You also don't wanna change the button so you can get rid of this line `varbtnX = document.getElementById("drikker-btn").innerHTML =` which sets the button to the result of the `fetch()` call, which in your case, because you don't await it, is a `Promise`.

Also, instead of using `innerHTML` you should use [`createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [`replaceChildren()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceChildren) (or [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)) to create new DOM elements and append them to existing ones.

I've used the [Fake Store API](https://fakestoreapi.com/) to give you a working example of what you need to do to get the desired output.

Comment: Removing the varbtnX = document.getElementById("drikker-btn").innerHTML = line seems to have fixed the issue. Thank you so much :) I am kinda new to programming, and have been scratching my head at this problem for hours.